# How can I install perf, a linux peformance monitoring tool?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I am trying to install perf. I searched online that it is available through http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/linux-tools, but I need apt. I have yum installed, but do not have apt so I tried installing apt via "yum install apt" but I get this message:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package apt available.
Nothing to do
```

Also, I have on my machines Red Hat AS5 and CentOS 5, not Ubuntu. Is installing from that Ubuntu repository okay?

Answer (score 10):

Just type in command line:

> yum install perf

(Dont forget sudo if you are not running as admin.)

Comment: I tried that. Seems like perf isn't found. Here's the message I get: yum install perf
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
2010Q4-rhas5-x86_64                                                                    |  951 B     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package perf available.
Nothing to do

Comment: @user1119779 did you try it on centos, I tried it on centos 6.2 and it worked perfectly? The problem might be something else for you, then. However I think the way to go via the apt thing, is not the right thing to do.

Comment: turns out it isn't available for centOS5. starts with centOS6. going to try to build from source...